# I want my parser to return a list of strings, but it returns a blank list

Tags: python, list, parsing, hex

I have a parser that reads in a long octet string, and I want it to print out smaller strings based on the parsing details. It reads in a hexstring which is as follows

The string will be in a format like so:

```
01046574683001000004677265300000000266010000
```

The format of the interface contained in the hex is like so:

```
version:length_of_name:name:op_status:priority:reserved_byte
```

==

```
01:04:65746830:01:00:00
```

== (when converted from hex)

```
01:04:eth0:01:00:00
```

^ this is 1 segment of the string , represents eth0 (I inserted the : to make it easier to read). At the minute, however, my code returns a blank list, and I don't know why. Can somebody help me please!

```
def octetChop(long_hexstring, from_ssh_):
    startpoint_of_interface_def=0
    # As of 14/8/13 , the network operator has not been implemented
    network_operator_implemented=False
    version_has_been_read = False
    position_of_interface=0
    chopped_octet_list = []

#This while loop moves through the string of the interface, based on the full length of the container
    try:
        while startpoint_of_interface_def < len(long_hexstring):

            if version_has_been_read == True:
                pass
            else:
                if startpoint_of_interface_def == 0:
                    startpoint_of_interface_def = startpoint_of_interface_def + 2
                    version_has_been_read = True

            endpoint_of_interface_def = startpoint_of_interface_def+2
            length_of_interface_name = long_hexstring[startpoint_of_interface_def:endpoint_of_interface_def]
            length_of_interface_name_in_bytes = int(length_of_interface_name) * 2 #multiply by 2 because its calculating bytes

            end_of_interface_name_point = endpoint_of_interface_def + length_of_interface_name_in_bytes
            hex_name = long_hexstring[endpoint_of_interface_def:end_of_interface_name_point]
            text_name = hex_name.decode("hex")

            print "the text_name is " + text_name

            operational_status_hex = long_hexstring[end_of_interface_name_point:end_of_interface_name_point+2]

            startpoint_of_priority = end_of_interface_name_point+2
            priority_hex = long_hexstring[startpoint_of_priority:startpoint_of_priority+2]

            #Skip the reserved byte
            network_operator_length_startpoint = startpoint_of_priority+4

            single_interface_string = long_hexstring[startpoint_of_interface_def:startpoint_of_priority+4]
            print single_interface_string + " is chopped from the octet string"# - keep for possible debugging

            startpoint_of_interface_def = startpoint_of_priority+4

            if network_operator_implemented == True:
                network_operator_length = long_hexstring[network_operator_length_startpoint:network_operator_length_startpoint+2]
                network_operator_length = int(network_operator_length) * 2
                network_operator_start_point = network_operator_length_startpoint+2
                network_operator_end_point = network_operator_start_point + network_operator_length
                network_operator = long_hexstring[network_operator_start_point:network_operator_end_point]
                #
                single_interface_string = long_hexstring[startpoint_of_interface_def:network_operator_end_point]

                #set the next startpoint if there is one
                startpoint_of_interface_def = network_operator_end_point+1
            else:
                self.network_operator = None

            print single_interface_string + " is chopped from the octet string"# - keep for possible debugging

            #This is where each individual interface is stored, in a list for comparison.
            chopped_octet_list.append(single_interface_string)
    finally:

        return chopped_octet_list
```

Comment: Your code seems overly complicated. Why do you have a `try` block when there are no exceptions to be caught? Why do you have a `from_ssh_` parameter that is never used? Why do you have a while loop with booleans to check your state within the loop when this parsing task doesn't seem to require iteration? You can calculate all the indices in one shot. Why is the input string contain a bunch of extra digits that don't show in the output string? All of these issues make it really hard to decipher your question and your code. I would like to help you but please clarify your question/code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is returning a blank list is the following: In this line:

```
    else:
        self.network_operator = None
```

`self` is not defined so you get a **NameError** exception. This means that the `try` jumps directly to the the `finally` clause without ever executing the part where you:

```
chopped_octet_list.append(single_interface_string)
```

As a consequence the list remains empty. In any case the code is overly complicated for such a task, I would follow one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got you right. You got a hex-string which contains various interface definition. Inside each interface definition the second octet describes the length of the name of the interface.

Lets say the string contains the interfaces eth0 and eth01 and looks like this (length 4 for eth0 and length 5 for eth01):

```
01046574683001000001056574683031010000
```

Then you can split it like this:

```
def splitIt (s):
    tokens = []
    while s:
        length = int (s [2:4], 16) * 2 + 10 #name length * 2 + 10 digits for rest
        tokens.append (s [:length] )
        s = s [length:]
    return tokens
```

This yields:

```
['010465746830010000', '01056574683031010000']
```

Answer (score 0):

To add onto Hyperboreus's answer, here's a simple way to parse the interface strings once you split them:

```
def parse(s):
    version = int(s[:2], 16)
    name_len = int(s[2:4], 16)
    name_end = 4 + name_len * 2
    name = s[4:name_end].decode('hex')
    op_status = int(s[name_end:name_end+2], 16)
    priority = int(s[name_end+2:name_end+4], 16)
    reserved = s[name_end+4:name_end+6]
    return version, name_len, name, op_status, priority, reserved
```

Here's the output:

```
>>> parse('010465746830010000')
(1, 4, 'eth0', 1, 0, '00')
```

Comment: Now to join Lanaru's and mine, you can do: `[parse (_) for _ in splitIt (s)]`, being s your raw string, and you get a list of nicely parsed interface definitions.

Comment: Maybe you would like to put a `int (?, 16)` around the string splices for version, status, and prio. Also I fear that you parse the length as though it were in decimal representation and not hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following helps. Call `parse` method below and pass a string stream into it, then iterate to get card infos (hope I got you right :)) `parse` will return you tuple(s) of the desired info.

```
>>> def getbytes(hs):
    """Returns a generator of bytes from a hex string"""
    return (int(hs[i:i+2],16) for i in range(0,len(hs)-1,2))

>>> def get_single_card_info(g):
    """Fetches a single card info from a byte generator"""
    v = g.next()
    l = g.next()
    name = "".join(chr(x) for x in map(lambda y: y.next(),[g]*l))
    return (str(v),name,g.next(),g.next(),g.next())

>>> def parse(hs):
    """Parses a hex string stream and returns a generator of card infos"""
    bs = getbytes(hs)
    while True:
        yield get_single_card_info(bs)


>>> c = 1
>>> for card in parse("01046574683001000001056574683031010000"):
    print "Card:{0} -> Version:{1}, Id:{2}, Op_stat:{3}, priority:{4}, reserved:{5} bytes".format(c,*card)
    c = c + 1


Card:1 -> Version:1, Id:eth0, Op_stat:1, priority:0, reserved:0 bytes
Card:2 -> Version:1, Id:eth01, Op_stat:1, priority:0, reserved:0 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyparsing includes a built-in expression for parsing a counted array of elements, so this would take care of your 'name' field nicely. Here's the whole parser:

```
from pyparsing import Word,hexnums,countedArray

# read in 2 hex digits, convert to integer at parse time
octet = Word(hexnums,exact=2).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0],16))

# read in a counted array of octets, convert to string
nameExpr = countedArray(octet, intExpr=octet)
nameExpr.setParseAction(lambda t: ''.join(map(chr,t[0])))

# define record expression, with named results
recordExpr = (octet('version') + nameExpr('name') + octet('op_status') +
              octet('priority') #+ octet('reserved'))
```

Parsing your sample:

```
sample = "01046574683001000004677265300000000266010000"
for rec in recordExpr.searchString(sample):
    print rec.dump()
```

Gives:

```
[1, 'eth0', 1, 0]
- name: eth0
- op_status: 1
- priority: 0
- version: 1
[0, 'gre0', 0, 0]
- name: gre0
- op_status: 0
- priority: 0
- version: 0
[0, 'f\x01', 0, 0]
- name: f
- op_status: 0
- priority: 0
- version: 0
```

The dump() method shows results names that you can use to access the individually parsed bits, like `rec.name` or `rec.version`.

(I commented out the reserved byte, else the second entry wouldn't parse correctly. Also, the third entry contains a name with a \x01 byte.)